# How to check if a sql returns NonType data in python

Tags: python, mysql

I am running a sql in python which returns multiple number of records (of the order of millions) and somewhere in between I am getting a data of `NonType` which is causing me issues as :`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`. My sql is:

`select col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7 from table1 where ....`

This sql generates multiple records and I want to find out which record/column has that `NoneType` data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve it on the Python level, you can iterate over the results and use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to detect any `None` values in a row:

```
for result in cursor.fetchall():
    if any(field is None for field in result):
        print(result)
        break  # break once we meet a row with None value
```

But, why don't solve it on the database level? For instance, find all rows where any of the columns have NULL value:

```
select 
    col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7 
from 
    table1 
where
    (col1 IS NULL or col2 IS NULL or ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

None is returned by the mysql adapter whenever a cell in the database contains a NULL. If you want to check the record's column for None you can do it with something like

```
if foo is None:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question but as documentation, here is an example

which replaces `None` with empty String `""`

I run into a similar problem with an sqlite database containing Null values.

```
non_null = lambda x: "" if x is None else x
list = []
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Table"):
    # replace None          
    ls = map(non_null,row)

    # create a new tuple because tuples are read-only
    row1 = tuple(ls)
    list.append(row1)

 print(list)
```